# Forward looking estimation of market price of risk of stochastic volatility

Tags: stochastic-volatility, risk-premium

I would like to estimate the market price of stochastic volatility by forward looking methods, such as option values. The stochastic volatility model I have in mind is the Heston model or some other similar ones. I am advised to look into the shorting positions of variance or volatility swaps and the return of the delta hedged SPX option positions. What are the relevant reference for these methodologies? Other suggestions are welcome.